# Undesired result from db:raw

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have taken a few answers from both SO and the Laravel forums to piece together the results. However, I am having an `Undefined variable error` and I'm not sure why.

### Controller

```
public function getJobs()

        {
            $query = DB::table('jobs');

            if (isset($jcategory))
            $query->where('category', '=', $jcategory);

            $result = $query->get();
           return View::make('jobsearch.search', $result);
        }
```

### View (has been abbreviated for space)

```
<form action="{{ action('JobsearchController@getJobs') }}" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 columns">
      <input type="text" name="realm" placeholder="Keywords/Skills" />
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <select name="jcategory">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
        <option value="jc1">Accounting</option>
```

...

```
 </select>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
       <input type="submit" value="Search" style="width:100%; padding-top: .5rem;
padding-bottom: .5rem;" class="button border-btn" />
      </div>


</div>
</form>

@foreach ($result as $job)
    <p>{{ $job->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Once I get this little test working I will add the rest of the `isset` into the `$query`. What I am trying to achieve is that the view will load all jobs in the database and if the user changes the category (for example) and submits the view it will reload the page with the reflected changes in the query.

I currently get an `Undefined variable: result` error on the view. I have tried the `foreach` in different ways but I have a feel that the controller isn't passing anything through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed the `$result` variable the wrong way. Try this:

```
return View::make('jobsearch.search')->with('result', $result);
```

Comment: That worked quite well, the page now loads and displays the id's however, when i submit the form even with the `{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'jobs/search')) }}` it spits out a `NotFoundHttpException` error.

Comment: @RohanPeters Probably because the route doesn't exist or you POST to a GET method. You have to create a method that deals with the storage of the data, then create a POST route for it and pass that to your form action.