# Laravel 4, ->withInput(); = Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, laravel

I have had a lengthy search both here and the Laravel forums, but i can't find an answer to this problem. `->withInput()` coughs up an `Undefined offset: 0`.

For Context:

Controller

```
public function getJobs()

        {
            $position_options = DB::table('jposition')->lists('friendly','id');
            $category_options = DB::table('jcategory')->lists('friendly','id');
            $location_options = DB::table('jlocation')->lists('friendly','id');



            $result = $query->get();
            return View::make('jobsearch.search', array('position_options' => $position_options, 'category_options' => $category_options, 'location_options' => $location_options))->withInput();

        }
```

View

```
<form action="{{ action('JobsearchController@getJobs') }}" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 columns">
      <input type="text" name="realm" placeholder="Keywords/Skills" />
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
       {{ Form::select('category', $category_options , Input::old('category')) }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="large-4 columns">
      {{ Form::select('location', $location_options , Input::old('location')) }}
    </div>


    <div class="large-4 columns">
      {{ Form::select('type', $position_options , Input::old('type')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
       <input type="submit" value="Search" style="width:100%; padding-top: .5rem;
padding-bottom: .5rem;" class="button border-btn" />
      </div>


</div>
</form>
```

Now according to the documentation there should not be an issue, and the page loads fine if the `->withInput();` is removed.

The end goal is to roll in the answer that i received from my previous question [Undesired result from db:raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001054/undesired-result-from-dbraw) and have a single page that loads the "Filtering" form and displays the relevant results on the reload and remembers the selections in the form.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Following a comment i have updated the controller and routes, still same result:

routes.php

`Route::get('jobs/search', 'JobsearchController@getSearch');`

&

`Route::post('jobs/search', 'JobsearchController@getJobs');`

Controller

```
 public function getSearch()
        {
                    $position_options = DB::table('jposition')->lists('friendly','id');
            $category_options = DB::table('jcategory')->lists('friendly','id');
            $location_options = DB::table('jlocation')->lists('friendly','id');

            return View::make('jobsearch.search', array('position_options' => $position_options, 'category_options' => $category_options, 'location_options' => $location_options));
        }

        public function getJobs()

        {
            $position_options = DB::table('jposition')->lists('friendly','id');
            $category_options = DB::table('jcategory')->lists('friendly','id');
            $location_options = DB::table('jlocation')->lists('friendly','id');


            return View::make('jobsearch.search', array('position_options' => $position_options, 'category_options' => $category_options, 'location_options' => $location_options))->withInput();

        }
```

Comment: I am new to laravel myself but when you first load the view, you wouldn't have any `Inputs` would you?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`withInput()` is only a method on the `Redirect` class. It is not available on the `View` class.

Calling `View.withInput($data)` has different behavior: it passes the following key value pair to your view: `'input' => $data`. This causes an error in your code because you're not passing any data to the function.

To get the behavior that you want, call `Input::flash()` before making your view, instead of calling `withInput()`. This will allow you to use the `Input::old()` function in your view to access the data.

Alternatively, you could pass `Input::all()` to your view, and use the `input[]` array in your view:

```
View::make(...)->withInput(Input::all());
```

which is translated to

```
View::make(...)->with('input', Input::all());
```

Comment: TonyArra your answer helped solve the issue, just want to clarify. Can i add `->with('result', $result);` after the `->withInput(Input::all());` with no adverse effects? Or does it need to be re-structured some way?

Comment: @RohanPeters I believe you can, but what I would recommend is building a $data array with everything you need in it, so that you can call your view like so `return View::make(jobsearch.search, $data)`