# laravel Undefined offset: 0

Tags: laravel

I am trying to diplay an error mesasge in case the field selected is duplicated in db.For this I am using laravel validation required unique. I am having problem with redirect
Here is store controller

```
 public function store() {
        $rules = array(
            'car' => array('required', 'unique:insur_docs,car_id'),
        );

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validation->fails()) {
            // Validation has failed.
            return Redirect::to('insur_docs/create')->with_input()->with_errors($validation);
        } else {
            $data = new InsurDoc();
            $data->ownership_cert = Input::get('ownership_cert');
            $data->authoriz = Input::get('authoriz');
            $data->drive_permis = Input::get('drive_permis');
            $data->sgs = Input::get('sgs');
            $data->tpl = Input::get('tpl');
            $data->kasko = Input::get('kasko');
            $data->inter_permis = Input::get('inter_permis');
            $data->car_id = Input::get('car');
            $data->save();
            // redirect
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    }
```

Here is the route

```
Route::get('insur_docs/create', array('as' => 'insur_docs.create','uses' => 'Insur_DocController@create'));
```

create controller

```
public function create() {


     $cars = DB::table('cars')->orderBy('Description', 'asc')->distinct()->lists('Description', 'id');
        return View::make('pages.insur_docs_create', array(
                    'cars' => $cars
        ));

}
```

insur_docs_create.blade.php

```
<div id="div-1" class="body">
            {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'insur_docs/store', 'class'=>'form-horizontal','id'=>'inline-validate')) }} 
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('ownership_cert', 'Ownership Certificate', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::select('ownership_cert', array('' => '', '1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'), '',  array(
                                'data-validation' => 'required', 
                                'data-validation-error-msg' => 'You did not enter a valid ownership certificate',
                                'class' => 'form-control'))
                    }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('authoriz', 'Authorization', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}            
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Helpers\Helper::date('authoriz', '' , array(
                                'data-validation' => 'required', 
                                'data-validation-error-msg' => 'You did not enter a valid authorization date',
                                'class' => 'form-control')) 
                    }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('drive_permis', 'Drive Permission', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::select('drive_permis', array('' => '', '1' => 'Active', '0' => 'Not active'),  '',  array(
                                'data-validation' => 'required', 
                                'data-validation-error-msg' => 'You did not enter a valid drive permission',
                                'class' => 'form-control'))
                    }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('sgs', 'SGS', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Helpers\Helper::date('sgs', '' , array(
                                'data-validation' => 'required', 
                                'data-validation-error-msg' => 'You did not enter a valid sgs date',
                                'class' => 'form-control')) 
                    }}
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('tpl', 'TPL', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Helpers\Helper::date('tpl', isset($v->sgs) ? $v->sgs : '' , array(
                                'data-validation' => 'required', 
                                'data-validation-error-msg' => 'You did not enter a valid tpl date',
                                'class' => 'form-control')) 
                    }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('kasko', 'Kasko', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Helpers\Helper::date('kasko', isset($v->kasko) ? $v->kasko : '' , array(
                                'data-validation' => 'required', 
                                'data-validation-error-msg' => 'You did not enter a valid kasko date',
                                'class' => 'form-control')) 
                    }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('inter_permis', 'International Permission', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Helpers\Helper::date('inter_permis', '' , array(
                                'data-validation' => 'required', 
                                'data-validation-error-msg' => 'You did not enter a valid international permission date',
                                'class' => 'form-control')) 
                    }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('car', 'Car', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::select('car', $cars, Input::old('class'), array(
                                'data-validation' => 'required',  
                                'data-validation-error-msg' => 'You did not enter a valid car',
                                'class' => 'form-control')) 
                    }}
                    {{ $errors->first('car') }}
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-line')) }}
            <input type="button" value="Back" class="btn btn-danger btn-line" onClick="history.go(-1);
                    return true;">
            <div>
                @foreach($errors as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

I t displays this error :

> Undefined offset: 0

Comment: It might be due to the unique part. You are setting the car as unique in both insur_docs and car_id tables. I'm guessing those two are not actually tables, but are just data within the table. So if you had a table of cars, you would set the car value unique to the cars table. e.g. 'car' => array('unique:cars')

Comment: But what does your create method look like?

Comment: @CheckeredMichael I have a table named "insur_docs" and has a field car_id. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just checked the Laravel docs and the unique part is actually correct, so sorry for that. If the error is coming up before you've even submitted your data, then you need to take a look at the create method and the error should lie in there.

Comment: no its' comming after submit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be that you are using a `get`, using `post` might help. Other than that you are mixing `model` and `controller` code. It's always a good idea to seperate these. For instance your redirects should be done inside the controller and not in the model.

- http://laravel.com/docs/validation
- http://laravelbook.com/laravel-input-validation/
- http://culttt.com/2013/07/29/creating-laravel-4-validation-services/

It's also better to do stuff on `$validator->passes()` and then `else` return with errors.

Controller

```
public function store() {

    $data = [
       "errors" => null
    ];

    $rules = array(
        'car' => array('required', 'unique:insur_docs,car_id')
    );

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validation->passes()) {
        $data = new InsurDoc();
        $data->ownership_cert = Input::get('ownership_cert');
        $data->authoriz = Input::get('authoriz');
        $data->drive_permis = Input::get('drive_permis');
        $data->sgs = Input::get('sgs');
        $data->tpl = Input::get('tpl');
        $data->kasko = Input::get('kasko');
        $data->inter_permis = Input::get('inter_permis');
        $data->car_id = Input::get('car');
        $data->save();
        return Redirect::to('/');
    } else {
        $data['errors'] = $validation->errors();
        return View::make('pages.insur_docs_create', $data);
    }

}
```

Your errors will be available in your view under `$errors`. Just do a `{{var_dump($errors)}}` in your `blade` template to verify that they are there.

View

```
@if($errors->count() > 0)
  <p>The following errors have occurred:</p>

  <ul>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $message)
      <li>{{$message}}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: That is weird because the object does exist! Can you empty the `$rules` array to see if something is wrong there? The `Validator::make` creates the object. It should work with an empty rules array.

Comment: Just for clarity, your code will work if you put validation in your controller, but if you want to be strict on your best practices you should put it in the model. But take your time you will learn! ;)

Comment: if I empty the $rules array it shows sql error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '61' for key 'car-id' (SQL: insert into `insur_docs` (`ownership_cert`, `authoriz`, `drive_permis`, `sgs`, `tpl`, `kasko`, `inter_permis`, `car_id`) values (, , , , , , , 61))

Comment: yes I know that the best practise is to put it in model but in my case it shows this error. Anyway I have edited my question

Comment: Are you still getting the error, because I forgot the `->all()` after `errors()` in my answer. Stupid!

Comment: no that's the error that I want to display with validation for duplicated values

Comment: the all after errors where? it is there and displays again this error: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to a member function errors() on a non-object

Comment: `$data['errors'] = $validation->errors()->all();` the 'i' in validation was missing. The same code now works for me and it's giving me errors back!

Comment: ok good, but now displays this at view object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)#122 (2) { ["messages":protected]=> array(0) { } ["format":protected]=> string(8) ":message" }  how to format it as i want and add styles?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52327/discussion-between-user3592644-and-sidneydobber)

Comment: you forgot validation styles :/

Comment: yes to display it with red borders or something. I have created a function   public static function macro($field, $errors) {
        if ($errors->has($field)) {
            $msg = $errors->first($field);
            return "<span style=\"color:red\" class=\"error\">$msg</span>";
        }
        return '';
    }

Comment: but this doesn't add any style :/ just red color

Comment: or this    public static function macro($field, $errors) {
        if ($errors->has($field)) {
            $msg = $errors->first($field);
            return "<div class=\"col-sm-5\">"
            . "<span class=\"help-block\">"
                    . "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign\">"
                    . "</span> $msg</span>"
                    . "</div>";
        }
        return '';
    } but doesn't has red borders :/

Comment: pls take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568538/filled-fields-are-going-empty-after-validation

Answer (score 1):

I Think this is a really better answer from this refrenece
[Laravel 4, ->withInput(); = Undefined offset: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027830/laravel-4-withinput-undefined-offset-0)

`withInput()` doesn't work the way you think it does. It's only a function of Redirect, not View.

Calling `withInput($data)` on View has a completely different effect; it passes the following key value pair to your `view: 'input' => $data` (you get an error because you're not passing any data to the function)

To get the effect that you want, call `Input::flash()` before making your view, instead of calling `withInput()`. This should allow you to use the `Input::old()` function in your view to access the data.

Alternatively, you could simply pass `Input::all()` to your view, and use the `input[]` array in your view:

```
View::make(...)->withInput(Input::all());
```

which is translated to

```
View::make(...)->with('input', Input::all());
```

As for your comment, I recommend doing it like so:

```
$position_options = DB::table('jposition')->lists('friendly','id');
$category_options = DB::table('jcategory')->lists('friendly','id');
$location_options = DB::table('jlocation')->lists('friendly','id');
$category = Input::get('category');
$location = Input::get('location');
$type = Input:: get('type'); 

$data = compact('position_options', 'category_options', 'location_options', 'category', 'type', 'location');

return View::make('jobsearch.search', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

also thinks about laravel resource controller. because when we call no parameter get method, it redirects to the show method with ignoring our function name.

eg:-Route::get('hasith', 'Order\OrderController@hasith');----->
       this parameter rederect to this function

```
   public function show($id, Request $request) {
            //code
   }
```