# filled fields are going empty after validation

Tags: validation, laravel

I have created an laravel form with validation, the problem here is that when I leave empty fields it displays the error message (that's ok) but then if I fill some field it and others not it makes a refresh and then the field that was filled now is empty and an error message for that field is displayed too.

```
public function store() {
        $data = [
            "errors" => null
        ];
        $rules = array(
            "car" => "required|unique:insur_docs,car_id", 
            "ownership_cert" => "required",
            "authoriz" => "required",            
            "drive_permis" => "required",
            "sgs" => "required",
            "tpl" => "required",
            "kasko" => "required",
            "inter_permis" => "required",
        );
        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        $cars = DB::table('cars')->orderBy('Description', 'asc')->distinct()->lists('Description', 'id');  
        if ($validation->passes()) {
            $doc = new InsurDoc();
            $doc->ownership_cert = Input::get('ownership_cert');
            $doc->authoriz = Input::get('authoriz');
            $doc->drive_permis = Input::get('drive_permis');
            $doc->sgs = Input::get('sgs');
            $doc->tpl = Input::get('tpl');
            $doc->kasko = Input::get('kasko');
            $doc->inter_permis = Input::get('inter_permis');
            $doc->car_id = Input::get('car');
            $doc->save();
            return Redirect::to('/');
        } else {
            $data['errors'] = $validation->errors();
            $data['cars'] = $cars;
                return View::make('pages.insur_docs_create', $data);
        }
    }
```

view

```
@if($errors->count() > 0)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p>The following errors have occurred:</p>

                        <ul>
                            @foreach($errors->all() as $message)
                            <li>{{ Helpers\Helper::macro($message) }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    @endif
```

macro function

```
public static function macro($errors) {
            return   "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign\">"
                    . "</span> $errors";

    }
```

What is going wrong there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Input::flash()` in your controller and use it in your view with `Input::old('field_name')`.

```
            Input::flash(); // Add this
            $data['errors'] = $validation->errors();
            $data['cars'] = $cars;
                return View::make('pages.insur_docs_create', $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks , just another problem with this is that when I refresh the page no field is displayed :/ because we are putting validation at store ?

Comment: any idea how to solve this ? does your page makes the same when refresh?