# ErrorException Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a newby on Laravel framework. I try to run my friend project on my pc and get an error when opening a certain menu and when I run the code on my browser, it shows ErrorException `(E_NOTICE)` `Undefined offset: 0`. How i have to do to solve this error?

This is the controller that handle the menu

```php
public function getViewPesananCust(){
        $userId = Auth::user()->id;
        $data['transaksi'] = Transaction::select('*', 'transaction.id as id_transaksi')
        ->join('users as pemesan', 'pemesan.id', 'transaction.id_user')
        ->where('transaction.id_user', '=', $userId)
        ->orderBy('timestamp', 'DESC')->get();
        $data['rating_user'] = array();
        $x = Transaction::where('id_user', $userId)->where('status_transaksi', 1)->orderBy('timestamp', 'DESC')->get();
        $a = array();
        foreach($x as $y) {
            $z = Transaksi::where('id_transaksi', $y['id_transaksi'])->get()[0];
            array_push($a, $z);
        }
        $b = array();
        foreach($a as $y) {
            $z = Menu::where('id',$y['id_menu'])->get()[0];
            array_push($b, $z);
        }
        $c = array();
        foreach($b as $y) {
            $z = Rating::where('id_menu', $y['id'])->get()[0];
            array_push($c, $z);
        }
        $data['rating_user'] = $c;

        return view('pesanan', $data);
    }
```

Comment: replace `->get()[0]` with `->first()` Here is documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel Undefined offset: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538053/laravel-undefined-offset-0)

Answer (score 0):

Since your first loop is on a collection its loop fine but for second loop you need to use key value pair as it loops on associative array.

```
       foreach($a as $key=>$value) {
          $z = Menu::where('id',$value['id_menu'])->get()[0];
          array_push($b, $z);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Query to database may return empty result. You need to check data present in query result before use it.

```
   public function getViewPesananCust(){
        $userId = Auth::user()->id;
        $data['transaksi'] = Transaction::select('*', 'transaction.id as id_transaksi')
        ->join('users as pemesan', 'pemesan.id', 'transaction.id_user')
        ->where('transaction.id_user', '=', $userId)
        ->orderBy('timestamp', 'DESC')->get();
        $data['rating_user'] = array();
        $x = Transaction::where('id_user', $userId)->where('status_transaksi', 1)->orderBy('timestamp', 'DESC')->get();
        $a = array();
        foreach($x as $y) {
            // check empty records
            $d1 = Transaksi::where('id_transaksi', $y['id_transaksi'])->get();
            if($d1 && count(d1) > 0){
                $z = $d1[0];
                array_push($a, $z);
            }
        }
        $b = array();
        foreach($a as $y) {
            $d2 = Menu::where('id',$y['id_menu'])->get();
            // check empty records
            if($d2 && count(d2) > 0){
                $z = $d2[0];
                array_push($b, $z);
            }
        }
        $c = array();
        foreach($b as $y) {                
            $d3 = Menu::where('id',$y['id_menu'])->get();
            // check empty records
            if($d3 && count(d3) > 0){
                $z = $d3[0];
                array_push($c, $z);
            }
        }
        $data['rating_user'] = $c;

        return view('pesanan', $data);
    }
```